# Transação Java / SqlServer dividida em vários métodos

Tags: java, jdbc

Tenho um método que executa vários `Prepared Statements`, só que dois deles em métodos de outras classes. No meu método, tenho o objeto `connection`, e se quiser iniciar uma transação, tenho que fazer:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false); 
connection.commit();
```

e no caso de exceção, fazer também o *rollback*. Mas o meu método chama outros métodos com outros objetos do tipo *connection*, aqui está a minha dúvida, como inicio a transação?

Meu método:

```
 public void insereProduto(Produto produto, ProdutoDesc productDesc, ArrayList<Autor> autores) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    DatabaseNET connection = new DatabaseNET();

    PreparedStatement sp = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO products(products_quantity, products_image,products_price,products_date_added,products_last_modified,products_date_available,products_weight,products_status,products_tax_class_id,manufacturers_id,products_ordered,editoras_id,coleccoes_id,tipoproduto_id,condicoes_id,products_code,specials_id,products_ano) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    sp.setFloat(1, 99998);
    sp.setString(2, produto.getProducts_image());
    sp.setFloat(3, produto.getProducts_price());
    sp.setDate(4, produto.getProducts_date_added());
    sp.setDate(5, produto.getProducts_last_modified());
    sp.setDate(6, produto.getProducts_date_available());
    sp.setFloat(7, produto.getProducts_weight());
    sp.setBoolean(8, produto.getProducts_status());
    sp.setInt(9, produto.getProducts_tax_class_id());
    sp.setInt(10, produto.getManufacturers_id());
    sp.setInt(11, produto.getProducts_ordered());
    sp.setInt(12, produto.getEditoras_id());
    sp.setInt(13, produto.getColeccoes_id());
    sp.setInt(14, produto.getTipoproduto_id());
    sp.setInt(15, produto.getCondicoes_id());
    sp.setString(16, produto.getProducts_code());
    sp.setInt(17, produto.getSpecials_id());
    sp.setInt(18, produto.getProducts_ano());

    sp.executeUpdate();

    ResultSet rs = sp.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();

    int product_id = rs.getInt(1);
    int category_id = produto.getCategory_id();

    insereProdutoCategoria(product_id, category_id);

    productDesc.setProducts_id(product_id);
    productDesc.insereProdutoDesc(productDesc);

    for (Autor autor : autores) {
        Autor autor_novo_produto = new Autor().getAutorByX3Autor(autor.getName());

        ProdutoAutor produto_autor_novo = new ProdutoAutor(product_id, Integer.parseInt(autor_novo_produto.getCod()), "", "", 0);
        produto_autor_novo.insereProdutoAutor(produto_autor_novo);

    }

    System.err.println("INSERT => "+product_id);
}
```

O meu método DatabaseNET:

```
public class DatabaseNET {
private static final String host = "jdbc:mysql://******"; 
private static final String database ="****";
private static final String port = "3306";
private static final String user = "****"; 
private static final String password = "****"; 

public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {  

    String connect = host+":"+port+"/"+database+"?user="+user+"&password="+password;

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connect);
        return conn;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseX3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Para gerar a uma execpção estou a inserir o "ahahah" no método:

```
 public void insereProdutoDesc(DatabaseNET connection, ProdutoDesc produto) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        PreparedStatement sp = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO products_description(products_id,language_id,products_name,products_description,products_url,products_viewed,products_autores_texto,products_autores_textofinal) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        sp.setInt(1, produto.getProducts_id());
        sp.setInt(2, produto.getLanguage_id());
        sp.setString(3, produto.getProducts_name());
        sp.setString(4, produto.getProducts_description().trim());
        sp.setString(5, produto.getProducts_url());
        sp.setString(6, "AHAHAHA");
        //sp.setInt(6, produto.getProducts_viewed());
        sp.setString(7, produto.getProducts_autores_texto());
        sp.setString(8, produto.getProducts_autores_textofinal());

        sp.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoDesc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Não é só criar um objeto da outra classe e chamar o método dela? Ah, em Java chamamos de "métodos" ao invés de "funções", pois um método é uma função que implicitamente possui uma referência do objeto da classe, bom, isso não é importante agora, mas senti obrigação em falar.

Comment: Sim, é um método, obrigado pela correção. Estou habituado ao php. A minha dúvida é: no meu método, tenho o objecto connection, e se quiser iniciar uma transação, tenho que fazer:
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

Commit -> connection.commit(); e no caso de excepção o rollback, mas o meu método chama outros métodos com outros objectos do tipo connection, aqui está a minha dúvida, como inicio a transação?

Comment: Entendi sua pergunta, vou tentar escrever uma resposta já já (caso não respondam antes). Senti a liberdade em transpor o conteúdo do seu comentário para o corpo da pergunta pois acredito que isso encoraja quem chegar agora, já que fica mais fácil para quem tentar entender.

Comment: Acho que o ideal é abrir o connection várias vezes, uma vez dentro de cada método. Se você precisar fazer o rollback em um deles você pode lançar uma exceção ou retornar um _false_, daí vc faz o _rollback_ no método anterior tb. Acha que isso resolve? A propósito, você está procurando apenas um jeito que funcione ou qual seria o melhor jeito dentre todos os possíveis?

Comment: Eu crio uma instância connection em cada class, mas nos testes que fiz, quando acontecia uma excepção ele nunca fazia o rollback as transacções realizadas no método anterior.

Mas tenho que fazer connection.setAutoCommit(false);

em cada método?

Comment: vou tentar passar a conexão como parâmetro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer que os métodos invocados executem seus comandos SQL dentro da mesma transação aberta pelo método principal, eles devem usar a mesma conexão aberta pelo método principal. Você tem que passar a conexão como parâmetro ou desenhar alguma outra forma de os métodos compartilharem a conexão existente.

Nós não conhecemos sua classe `DatabaseNET` e a solução exata depende disso. Eis uma sugestão de uma possível solução.
Observe que faltam coisas aí, como fechar a conexão.

Expliquei alterações que fiz no seu código em comentários no próprio código:

```
public void insereProduto(Produto produto, ProdutoDesc productDesc, ArrayList<Autor> autores) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    DatabaseNET connection = new DatabaseNET();

    PreparedStatement sp = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO products(products_quantity, products_image,products_price,products_date_added,products_last_modified,products_date_available,products_weight,products_status,products_tax_class_id,manufacturers_id,products_ordered,editoras_id,coleccoes_id,tipoproduto_id,condicoes_id,products_code,specials_id,products_ano) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    sp.setFloat(1, 99998);
    sp.setString(2, produto.getProducts_image());
    sp.setFloat(3, produto.getProducts_price());
    sp.setDate(4, produto.getProducts_date_added());
    sp.setDate(5, produto.getProducts_last_modified());
    sp.setDate(6, produto.getProducts_date_available());
    sp.setFloat(7, produto.getProducts_weight());
    sp.setBoolean(8, produto.getProducts_status());
    sp.setInt(9, produto.getProducts_tax_class_id());
    sp.setInt(10, produto.getManufacturers_id());
    sp.setInt(11, produto.getProducts_ordered());
    sp.setInt(12, produto.getEditoras_id());
    sp.setInt(13, produto.getColeccoes_id());
    sp.setInt(14, produto.getTipoproduto_id());
    sp.setInt(15, produto.getCondicoes_id());
    sp.setString(16, produto.getProducts_code());
    sp.setInt(17, produto.getSpecials_id());
    sp.setInt(18, produto.getProducts_ano());

    // inicia um try..catch para poder fazer rollback em caso de exceção
    try {
        // Inicia a transação antes do primeiro comando SQL.
        // Pelo que entendi, a transação já será aberta implicitamente pelo SGBD
        // e o setAutoCommit(false) é para que ela mantenha-se 
        // aberta depois do primeiro comando.
        connection.setAutoCommit(false); 

        sp.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = sp.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();

        int product_id = rs.getInt(1);
        int category_id = produto.getCategory_id();

        // Se você quer que os comandos executados dentro deste método participem
        // da mesma transação, eles devem utilizar a mesma conexão, 
        // a qual já tem uma transação aberta
        insereProdutoCategoria(connection, product_id, category_id);

        productDesc.setProducts_id(product_id);
        productDesc.insereProdutoDesc(productDesc);

        for (Autor autor : autores) {
            Autor autor_novo_produto = new Autor().getAutorByX3Autor(autor.getName());

            ProdutoAutor produto_autor_novo = new ProdutoAutor(product_id, Integer.parseInt(autor_novo_produto.getCod()), "", "", 0);

            // Mais uma vez a conexão, com a transação já aberta, 
            // sendo passada por parâmetro
            produto_autor_novo.insereProdutoAutor(connection, produto_autor_novo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Talvez você precise verificar se a conexão 
        // e a transação ainda estão abertas, isso depende da implementação de DatabaseNET
        if (connection.isOpen() && connection.isTransactionOpen()) {
            connection.rollback();
        }
        // Propaga a exceção para o chamador do método
        // saber que não funcionou.
        throw e;
    }
    // Se não houve exceção, commita
    connection.commit();
}
```

Minha intenção aqui é ajudar apenas com o problema exato que você levantou, então não vou lançar discussão sobre algumas coisas que podem ser melhoradas no seu design. Podemos discuti-las em outras perguntas caso você tenha interesse.

Comment: ok, obrigado. Vou tentar seguir a sua solução, e claro que gostava de discutir as melhorias

Comment: Coloquei o meu método DatabaseNET na minha pergunta para você poder ver, e um dos métodos para inserir os dados. 

Segui o seu exemplo, mas ele continua a não faz o rollback.

Comment: Por acaso `connection.getConnection()` cria uma nova conexão? Se sim, não vai funcionar como você deseja; é necessário usar a mesma conexão. Outro problema é o tratamento de exceções em `insereProdutoDesc`. Se os comandos SQL neste método falharem, a exceção será limpa e não vai cair no `catch` de `insereProduto`, ou seja, não haverá rollback. Na verdade creio que todos os seus `try..catch` estão errados. Por que você some com a exceção e escreve no log?

Comment: Vi esse meu bug agora, vou postar o meu código novo numa resposta.

Comment: Já vi o problema agora, realmente tinha esse bug de criar novas conexões mas também tinha o tipo de tabela como MySam e não innoDB. Muito obrigado pela resposta.